# How to turn distinct products into columns with the count as value

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table with customersID's and Products they have bought:

| CustomerId | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Apple |
| 3 | Orange |
| 3 | Banana |
| 7 | Orange |
| 7 | Orange |
| 7 | Banana |
| 9 | Apple |
| 9 | Apple |
| 9 | Banana |

I would like to create a column for each customer, with the amount of products they have bought of each distinct value:

| CustomerId | Apple | Orange | Banana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 | 0 | 1 |

For whatever reason, I'm having trouble finding a similar question online, which I suspect is due to my inability to formulate the question.

Comment: Youøre looking for the `PIVOT` function.

Comment: Do you know the list of product names up front, or does the query have to accommodate any new future values?

Comment: @AaronBertrand The list of product names is not known.

Comment: Try to work through [this example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), then come back with specific problems.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I began reading about the PIVOT function after SchmitzIT mentioned it, but the example in your link is exactly what I was looking for before asking my question. I will return with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I learned about dynamic PIVOT queries - transform columns into rows. Combined with dynamic queries (queries whose content is not fully known until runtime), you can use PIVOT queries without knowing all the values in your column, by adding the values to the query during runtime.

Taking my question as an example:

1. Create and populate the first table in the question, which we will call Sales:

   ```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Sales
    CREATE TABLE #Sales
    (
    CustomerID INT,
    Product      NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    );
    INSERT #Sales VALUES
    (3, N'Apple'),
    (3, N'Orange'),
    (3, N'Banana'),
    (7, N'Orange'),
    (7, N'Orange'),
    (7, N'Banana'),
    (9, N'Apple'),
    (9, N'Apple'),
    (9, N'Banana');
   ```
2. Group by CustomerID and Product to count the amount bought of each product:

   ```
    SELECT CustomerID
           , Product
           , COUNT(*) as Total_bought
    INTO #SalesSummed
    FROM #Sales
    GROUP BY CustomerID, Product
   ```
3. Add each distinct Product to the pivot query:

   ```
    DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @columns = N'';
    SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(Product)
    FROM (SELECT p.Product FROM #SalesSummed AS p
    GROUP BY p.Product) AS x;
    SET @sql = N'
    SELECT p.CustomerID, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
    INTO #SalesMatrix
    FROM
    (
        SELECT p.CustomerID, p.Product, p.Total_bought
        FROM #SalesSummed AS p
    ) AS j
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(Total_bought) FOR Product IN ('
        + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
        + ')
    ) AS p;';
    PRINT @sql;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
   ```

Step 3 yields the table SalesMatrix:

| CustomerID | Apple | Banana | Orange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | NULL | 1 | 2 |
| 9 | 2 | 1 | NULL |

Which is exactly what we wanted (we can replace NULL with 0)!

Comment: Unfortunately the code snippets are unreadble (and are html *not* sql). Try re-copying the code as text, and then use the code button `{}` to format it.

Comment: @SOS Sorry, on my end it was possible to compile the html into SQL. I had trouble using the {}, but turns out I just needed an extra indent. The code should be readible now :)